# ActiveRecord: Get all users who should be banned today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ban_messages, dependent: :destroy
end

class BanMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Table `BanMessage` contains a field `t.datetime :ban_date` that stores the date, when user should be banned. `User` table contains a field `status`, that contains one of the status values (active, suspended, banned). When I send BanMessage to User, his status field changes from 'active' to 'suspended'. Also I can activate user back, so he would not be banned at `':ban_date'`, but his BanMessage wouldn't be destroyed.
So I need to create query for selecting all Users with status 'suspended', who have in their newest BanMessages records 'ban_date' field, with DateTime value, which is between `'DateTime.now.beginning_of_day'` and `'DateTime.now.end_of_day'`.

Comment: Can you specify please what version of SQL you are wanting to use? - also can you paste your attempt at the query so far, and any of the tables and some sample data would be helpful

Comment: @jimmy8ball, I'm using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I needed:

```
User.joins(:ban_messages)
  .where('users.status = ?', :suspended)
  .where('ban_messages.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ban_messages.created_at) FROM ban_messages WHERE ban_messages.user_id = users.id)')
  .where('ban_messages.ban_date BETWEEN ? and ?',  DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day)
  .group('users.id')
```

**UPDATE**

> **MrYoshiji**: *The caveat in your code is that if you miss one day, then
>   the next day you won't see the people that should have been banned the
>   day before. You might want to get all User where the ban_date is
>   lesser than DateTime.now.end_of_day, either in the same view or
>   another one.*

So final query might be something like this

```
User.joins(:ban_messages)
  .where('users.status = ?', :suspended)
  .where('ban_messages.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ban_messages.created_at) FROM ban_messages WHERE ban_messages.user_id = users.id)')
  .where('ban_messages.ban_date < ?', DateTime.now.end_of_day)
  .group('users.id')
```

Comment: The caveat in your code is that if you miss one day, then the next day you won't see the people that should have been banned the day before. You might want to get all User where the ban_date is lesser than `DateTime.now.end_of_day`, either in the same view or another one.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, this code would work every day at 12am via cro. Do you think that may be a situation when cron wouldn't do its job? Then you are right.

Comment: well, yes. If your server is being rebooted at this exact moment, or the cron job fails to read the DB (db service down for example), or whatever, the script would not be executed, and that is something you do not want. The best way to handle this is to grab all records having a `ban date lesser or equal to today.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your users with `where` query followed by `join` method for associated `ban_messages` with `where` method to further filter with the date range.

```
User.where(status: 'suspended').joins(:ban_messages).where("ban_date >= ? AND ban_date <= ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day )
```

Comment: No, it show me users with old ban_messages with ban_date between DateTime.now.beginning_of_day and DateTime.now.end_of_day, even if user has newer ban_message with another ban_date.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

`User.joins(:ban_messages).where(status: :suspended).where('ban_messages.ban_date BETWEEN :begin_time AND :end_date', begin_time: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, end_time: DateTime.now.end_of_day)`

Comment: No, it show me users with old ban_messages with ban_date between DateTime.now.beginning_of_day and DateTime.now.end_of_day, even if user has newer ban_message with another ban_date.