# Get all messages between the current user and every admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have model `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'DirectMessage', foreign_key: :sender_user_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'DirectMessage', foreign_key: :receiver_user_id
end
```

and model `DirrectMessage`

```
class DirectMessage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :sender_user_id
  belongs_to :receiver_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :receiver_user_id
end
```

I need to write query to get all messages, where:

`sender_user_id = options[:current_user].id AND receiver_user.role = 'admin'` OR `receiver_user_id = options[:current_user].id AND sender_user.role = 'admin'`

I just need to get all messages between the current user and every admin.

For now, I was trying something like this:

```
DirectMessage.all.joins(:sender_user, :receiver_user).where('(sender_user_id = ? AND sender_user.role = ?) OR ( receiver_user_id = ? AND receiver_user.role = ?)', options[:current_user].id, 'admin', options[:current_user].id, 'admin')
```

but it returns me just `#<DirectMessage::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8ead7879c0>`. If I will try to get first record from it, I will get error:

> *** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sender_user" LINE 1:
>   ...r_id = 'b4de3f59-b234-459a-adb1-2a6c1a135919' AND sender_use...

Help me to write a proper query, please. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a working solution. First, we need to add scope to `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'DirectMessage', foreign_key: :sender_user_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'DirectMessage', foreign_key: :receiver_user_id

  scope :admin, -> { where(role: 'admin') }
end
```

So now query will look like this:

```
DirectMessage.all.where('(sender_user_id = :current_user_id AND receiver_user_id IN (:admin_ids)) OR (sender_user_id IN (:admin_ids) AND receiver_user_id = :current_user_id)',
                        current_user_id: options[:current_user].id, admin_ids: User.admin.ids)
```

I don't think, that there will be more than several dozens of admins, so this solution is pretty good.

Comment: Lol why are you answering your own questions with the answers others provide you?
You did the same thing here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458340/activerecord-get-all-users-who-should-be-banned-today

Pretty lame tbh....

Comment: @SickLickWill, don't be like a small offended boy. Your answer doesn't work as needed. My answer by your link I wrote by myself, but updated it in accordance with the user's comment, indicating his authorship.

Comment: You're a joke m8 ttyl ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method that passes the current_user value through to your model, current user is not available in the model, only view and controllers.
Note: You can define these methods as scopes or methods.

```
class DirectMessage < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def self.messages_from_user(user)
    where(sender_user: user, receiver_user: User.admins)
  end
end


class User < ApplicationRecord

...

  def self.admins
    where(role: 'admin')
  end
end

# then in your controller or view you can do 
@direct_messages = DirectMessage.messages_from_user(current_user)
```

Comment: In such case, I will not get incoming messages from admins, only outgoing. Look at my answer, I found a working solution.

Comment: Yeah you built upon the answer I gave you 

Comment: no, your way doesn't work as needed, it gives only outgoing messages from current_user to any admin. My solution gives all outgoing messages from current_user to any admin and all incoming messages from any admin to current_user. Next time read the question more carefully.

Comment: The aim of stackoverflow is to help people solve technical problems, not hand them their work completed on a silver platter. I showed you how to use scopes "Note: You can define these methods as scopes or methods.", I also gave you the method! `def self.admins
    where(role: 'admin')
  end`